# Problem with the widgets of GTK Theme

Tags: unity, themes, gtk, gtk3

I've been tweaking GTK Theme called "Yosembiance" to my taste. Basically I want to remove the orange accent color and use #9E9EB3 as the accent color.

I've installed `TheWidgetFactory` and all the widgets of GTK 2 seems to be exactly how I want them. I don't know how to check GTK 3 widgets.

Here is what I did so far:

- `gksudo gedit Yosembiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css` and changed the
  property of `selected_bg_color` from orange to #9E9EB3 and save.
- `gksudo gedit Yosembiance/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` and changed the
  preperty of `nselected_bg_color` from orange to #9E9EB3 and save.
- `gksudo gedit Yosembiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` and changed the property of
  `nselected_bg_color` from orange to #9E9EB3 and save.
- In `Yosembiance/gtk-3.0/assets` I changed the pixels of every icon that
  have orange pixels with #9E9EB3
- Reworked some of the icons in `Yosembiance/unity`

**The Problem**

Some of the widgets have combined colors of orange and #9E9EB3. Seems I have to modify some more files, but I don't know which ones.

***Here is a link with my theme***: [Click here to download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B168hSJtqPniNDlvWGpjU21ydkU/view?usp=sharing)

Any pointers?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Which Yosembiance's version have you chosen? Looking around the web there is more than one version.

Comment: I Download 1.1(Ubuntu 14.10) from here http://www.sundman.ca/themes/yosembiance/, I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, but I think this does not matter.

Comment: What about `gtk-widgets.css` in your gtk3 folder? Look for `mix` where two colors are used at one time. For example: `color: mix (@fg_color, shade (@bg_color, 0.95), 0.2);`

To save some trouble, you could copy the theme folders over to ~/.themes and play with them there avoiding gksudo.

Comment: I've searched gtk-main.css, settings.ini and gtkrc for other variables that store the orange color but there is none.

The other files use the properties in the variable of this three files to colorize their elements.

Comment: I think I've found the problem I've made a grep search for all the files in theme for the color #f07746 and it's says  that in settings.ini and gtkrc the property of seleted_bg_color is #f07746(orange). When I open the files using gksudo gedit it shows that the properties of the selected_bg_color are #9E9EB3. When I try to change again to #9E9EB3 I got errors in the console.

Comment: Just guessing here but have you looked at the css files in .../gtk-3.0/apps? Some colors are defined there as well. Then there are urls pointing to .svg as well.

Comment: @DKBose Check the update of the post.

Comment: I found the problem. Indeed it was in the gtk-widget.css file. The widgets that give me the problem were progresbar and gtkscale, they had defined colors in the background-color rule and didn't take their values from the variables.